# QGIS crashes every time I try to select the labels tab

Tags: qgis, labeling

Every time I open the Properties box and try to select the "Labels" tab, for any layer in any project, QGIS crashes "unexpectedly" as it says in its Problem Report. I'm using version 2.14.3.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling QGIS, but this doesn't help. The labels that I had turned on previously are still displayed, but I cannot edit them. I thought that it could have been a couple of corrupted layer files, but even if I begin a new blank project and create a brand new shapefile, as soon as I try to select the "Labels" tab, the whole program crashes.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Disable all plugins and try again.

Comment: Please share information about the operating system which you are using and the way you installed QGIS.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan, and I installed QGIS from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis, as linked from the qgis website. I installed all four pkg components in order (GDAL, NumPy, matplotlib, Install).  

I've tried disabling all plugins, but to no avail. Still, any time, under any conditions for any layer, if I open the properties box, then try to click the labels tab QGIS crashes and gives an error message saying it quit unexpectedly.